# GitHub actions with EFS fo AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-s3, github-actions, amazon-efs

I'm using github actions to deploy the code and ECS (elastic container service).
The container of web server is running at EC2 of ECS. The container has a bind mount folder at EC2, this folder is linked to EFS and the code of webserver is stored there.
I need to modify the github actions, to be able just to clone the repository and copy all the file to EFS. I've looked at the internet, but didn't find any solution.
Please advice